# Javascript Parse SDK saving twice

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform, save

I am a little bit confused about this code in the parse javascript SDK.

```
// Create the object.
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();

gameScore.set("score", 1337);
gameScore.set("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.set("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.set("skills", ["pwnage", "flying"]);

gameScore.save(null, {
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
    // will get sent to the cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
    gameScore.set("cheatMode", true);
    gameScore.set("score", 1338);
    gameScore.save();
  }
});
```

Can someone explain why it is saving twice?
https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-updating

[EDIT]
To be clear I understand there are two calls to .save();

I want to know why this code, which is straight from the parse Javascript SDK, is saving twice. Are there benefits or is this a mistake? I am not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is saving twice is because on a successful save of gameScore you are calling save again.

```
gameScore.save(null, {    //FIRST SAVE
    success: function(gameScore) {
        gameScore.set("cheatMode", true);
        gameScore.set("score", 1338);
        gameScore.save(); //SECOND SAVE
    }
});
```

On a successful save, you typically shouldn't be saving it again.

In the link you gave, they're just showing you that you can update gameScore with new data. It's not, generally, a practical use of the `save()` function.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is why is it that in the parse SDK they are doing this, why saving it twice? This code is straight from  their SDK.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's just an example they're showing. Not something that should be followed in most cases.